# How to chain predefined functions in WebStorm live template variables

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I am trying to give a name to a React component, based on a file name. E.g. if file name is `test-comp.js` component should be named as `TestComp`.

Thus I want to call built in functions of live templates this way:

```
capitalize(camelCase(fileNameWithoutExtension()))
```

However it does not work. I also tried doing it from 'Edit variables' window, but looks like I can only add one function expression there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be done in `Edit Template Variables` window; you can enter as many functions as you like there (but, of course, you have to type them - you can't enter complex expressions by selecting function from dropdown):

[image]